# What is the reason for the nil entry in Rails localisation month and day arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am using Rails i18n and I noticed that for months a nil must be entered (as mentioned in the documentation here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml#L15_) like this:

```
month_names: [~, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December]
```

as there is no such thing as a 0th month.

Why is this important, why isn't January just returned for the first element? How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because natural month numbers are `1`-based instead of being `0`-based like a typical array. In order to provide for that and avoid having to remember to perform the index calculation whenever it is needed, the month names array is just defined with the extra element at `zero` position.

Take a look at [date_helper code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a4acb4da6ed3df6b583c58dc28ac729a2f5d75c1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L892-L925) for an example of how it's used:

> ```
>     # Looks up month names by number (1-based):
>     #
>     #   month_name(1) # => "January"
>     #
>     # If the <tt>:use_month_numbers</tt> option is passed:
>     #
>     #   month_name(1) # => 1
>     #
>     # If the <tt>:use_two_month_numbers</tt> option is passed:
>     #
>     #   month_name(1) # => '01'
>     #
>     # If the <tt>:add_month_numbers</tt> option is passed:
>     #
>     #   month_name(1) # => "1 - January"
>     #
>     # If the <tt>:month_format_string</tt> option is passed:
>     #
>     #   month_name(1) # => "January (01)"
>     #
>     # depending on the format string.
>     def month_name(number)
>       if @options[:use_month_numbers]
>         number
>       elsif @options[:use_two_digit_numbers]
>         '%02d' % number
>       elsif @options[:add_month_numbers]
>         "#{number} - #{month_names[number]}"
>       elsif format_string = @options[:month_format_string]
>         format_string % {number: number, name: month_names[number]}
>       else
>         month_names[number]
>       end
>     end
> ```

Answer (score 1):

They probably just want the array index to correspond with the correct month so they stick a stub in front.

e.g.

```
months[12] = December
```